# Difference between LATERAL FLATTEN(...) and TABLE(FLATTEN(...)) in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral-join

What is the difference between the use of `LATERAL FLATTEN(...)` and `TABLE(FLATTEN(...))` in Snowflake? I checked the documentation on [`FLATTEN`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html), [`LATERAL`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) and [`TABLE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html) and cannot make heads or tails of a functional difference between the following queries.

```
select
    id as account_id,
    account_regions.value::string as region
from
    salesforce.accounts,
    lateral flatten(split(salesforce.accounts.regions, ', ')) account_regions
```

```
select
    id as account_id,
    account_regions.value::string as region
from
    salesforce.accounts,
    table(flatten(split(salesforce.accounts.regions, ', '))) account_regions
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll say that in the presented queries there's no difference - as the lateral join is implicit by the dynamic creation of a table out of the results of operating within values coming out of a row.

The real need for the `lateral` keyword comes out of queries like this:

```sql
select * 
from departments as d
  , lateral (
    select * 
    from employees as e 
    where e.department_id = d.department_id
  ) as iv2
order by employee_id;
-- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html
```

Without the `lateral` keyword for this join, you get an `Error: invalid identifier 'D.DEPARTMENT_ID'`.